# Pause all background animation during user-activated animation (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

So I have several sets of animations going on in the background. However, during a user animation I would like to pause all other animations so that the browser can render what the user needs best.

```
Element.mousein()  --> Pause (NOT STOP) all animations except those related to Element
                       i.e. $(body).not(Element).pauseAnimations();
Element.mouseout() --> Resume all animations
                       i.e. $(body).not(Element).resumeAnimations();
```

Something like this http://tobia.github.com/Pause/ but instead, pause all the other ones except the one that is hovered.

Comment: `Psuedocode"ish` code in question just wastes people's time (including yours). SHow how animations work if you want solid answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using stop() you'll have to specify every animate manual but I've just found [this (link)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/) which apparently allows to stop all current animations.

`$("button").click($.fx.off)`

---

Ok the above solution wasn't any good as you said it was a general selector.

`$("div:animated").not('#AnimationYouWantToContiune').stop();`

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmcng/) Ive managed to add 3 divs that are animating and when click a button it will stop all but the specified divs from animating. Does this help at all?

Comment: but that would stop all animations NOT all OTHER animations.

Comment: but you might be able to add an exception with the `.not()` selector like `$("button").click($.fx.off).not(this)`

Comment: $.fx.off is a global jquery variable that disables all animations. Not a per element variable which you can turn on and off. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you were right... my apologies. Please see my edit below my original answer.

Comment: can you make it resume from where it left off if i click it again..instead of making a new animation

Comment: Please see this updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vmcng/1/. It will stop and resume the animations on hover and hover off

Comment: you are actually starting a new animation instead of resuming where it left of.

Comment: I'll not be defeated and am determined to get to get those 15 reputation points back :) so have done some google and found this pause plugin  `http://tobia.github.com/Pause/` does this help?

Answer (score 2):

This is hard-to-use for the user since he/she should follow a moving box to keep it hovered. But animations other than positioning would be more usable of course.

Anyway, here is a modified version of the official Pause plugin [**demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/9GQra/).

What you should do inside the `setupBox()` function is:

```
function setupBox(i) {
    var $box = $('#box' + i);

    function phase1() {
        $box.animate({left: 100}, 1000, 'swing', phase2);
    }

    function phase2() {
        $box.animate({left: 0}, 1000, 'swing', phase1);
    }

    // This pauses rest of the boxes except the targeted. 
    // I added a class ('box') to each element to easily select all boxes. 
    // You could also do: $('.demo').children() since all the children are boxes.
    function pauseRest() {
        $('.box').not('#box' + i).pause(); 
        $box.resume();
    }

    $box.hover(function () {
        pauseRest($box);
    }, function () {
        $('.box').resume();
    });
    phase1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the animation when you need it to.

Comment: That means you have to go to each animation and say stop...but instead I want to generalize to something like this $(body).not(this).pauseAnimations();

Comment: you can assign a class to the elements and select on them, you don't need to go over each.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery like you own it...

jQuery has selector :not described [here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

This is an exmaple of pause plugin with pausing other elements than the one hoverd on;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://tobia.github.com/Pause/style.css'>
        <script src='http://tobia.github.com/Pause/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://github.com/tobia/Pause/raw/master/jquery.pause.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo">
            <div id="box1" class="boxy"></div>
            <div id="box2" class="boxy"></div>
            <div id="box3" class="boxy"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".boxy").each(function(){
                    $(this).hover(function() {
                        var id = $(this).attr("id");
                        $(":not(#" + id + ")").pause();
                    }, function() {
                        var id = $(this).attr("id");
                        $(":not(#" + id + ")").resume();
                    });
                    setupBox($(this));
                });
                function setupBox(elem) {
                    function phase1() {
                        elem.animate({ left: 450 }, 2000, 'swing', phase2);
                    }
                    function phase2() {
                        elem.animate({ left: 0 }, 2000, 'swing', phase1);
                    }
                    phase1();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)** function to delay execution of items in the queue, but this is not the preffered way to do it.

If you can, you should use the callback function in the [**animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.